# How render HTML Pages in Loopback project managed using IBM API Connect?

Tags: ibm-cloud, loopbackjs, apiconnect

In my usecase I am performing forgot password using Loopback API.

I will send forgot password page link to users via email, and from there user click on the link so that password reset page will be rendered and user completes the action.

I have given Forgot password link as below, it is showing (**This site can’t provide a secure connection Error**)

https://apiconnect-1233333-4e88-7878-5454-4454555454545.xxx-xxx.apic.mybluemix.net/reset-password?access_token=xxx

My question is
1) What link i should provide to access HTML page in API connect project ?

I am new to IBM Cloud, Kindly help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

API Connect provides ability to expose your backend functions as APIs and is available as a Service in IBM Cloud.  The exposed APIs are consumed by End User applications.  Are you trying to develop an Loopback API for providing forgotten password function?  If that is the case, have you a developed a Loopback API, tested it and published to IBM API Connect on Cloud?  Are you seeing the published API in the developer Portal and register an application to consume this API?

If you are new to IBM Cloud you can refer to the tutorials
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/11/new-tutorials-get-started-ibm-cloud/
If you are new to API Connect, you can refer to the tutorials
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/11/new-tutorials-get-started-ibm-cloud/